# if there is no running process in the OS, are the ready queue and device queues empty?

Tags: process, operating-system, queue

it's a hypothetical situation. If the ready queue is not empty, does that mean the running queue should also be not empty?

Comment: OS itself would be running as the kernel processes keeps on running for OS task. 2. Yes, if the ready queue isn't empty, then obviously the processes are still in the ready state and to be executed, so the running queue also can't be empty.